# Eclipse Unable To Find Variable

Tags: java, eclipse

I'm relatively new to Java (2 days to be exact) and I'm writing a guessing game in Eclipse. Every time I run it in the console I get this:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
numberofTries cannot be resolved to a variable

at GuessingGame.main(GuessingGame.java:35)
```

I'm following a tutorial and this is what my code is:

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class GuessingGame {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Random rand = new Random();
        int numberToGuess = rand.nextInt(1000);
        int numberOfTries = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        int guess;
        boolean win = false;

        while (win == false) {

            System.out.println("Guess a number between 1 and 1000: ");
            guess = input.nextInt();
            numberOfTries++;

            if (guess == numberToGuess) {
                win = true;
            }

        }
        if (guess < numberToGuess) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too low");

        }
        else if (guess > numberToGuess) {
            System.out.println("Your guess is too high");
        }
        System.out.println("You win!");
        System.out.println("The number was " + numberToGuess);
        System.out.println("It took you " + numberofTries + "tries");
    }
}
```

I double checked everything and everything was correct.

Comment: Typo: java is case-sensitive: `System.out.println("It took you " + numberofTries + "tries")`: `numberofTries` should be `numberOfTries`. Note the capital `O`

Comment: Note that in future, resolve all errors *before* you run. It's very rarely a good idea to run code which has errors. Usually Eclipse will ask you whether you're sure you want to run anyway if you try - just say no.

Answer (score 0):

Capitalization issue. `numberofTries` is not the same as `numberOfTries`, as the O in "of" isn't capitalized.

Answer (score 0):

In your last line there is a simple typo; that numberofTries should be numberOfTries (case sensitivity)

Answer (score 0):

Java is case sensitive!

System.out.println("It took you " + numberofTries + "tries");

Your variable name in this line is not the same as the variable you created, you probably just misstyped :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.Error: Unresolved compilation problem: 
numberofTries cannot be resolved to a variable

at GuessingGame.main(GuessingGame.java:35)
```

Use these error messages as guidance. It's quite literally telling you exactly what's going on.

At line 35, you have a variable named 'numberofTries' that's undefined.  As others have noted, the O in 'of' needs to be capitalized because Java is case-sensitive (as are most programming languages).